# Тестирование веб сервиса на golang

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты

Всем привет!Хочу протестировать свое приложение на golang,а именно функцию добавления нового пользователя.Идея такая:подсчитываю количество пользователей,создаю запрос на добавление нового, далее подсчитываю опять количество пользователей, которое должно быть +1. Не могу сообразить, как реализовать запрос с заполнением формы вот такого типа:

```
<form method="POST" action="useraded">
            <label>Enter firstname</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br><br>
```

handlers.go

```
    func AddNewUserFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //creating new instance and checking method
    newUser := &model.User{}
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/addNewUser.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)

    } else {
        resBool, errStr := checkFormValue(w, r, "firstname", "lastname")
        if resBool == false {
            t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/notSucceded.html")
            checkError(err)
            t.Execute(w, errStr)

            return
        }
        newUser.FirstName = r.FormValue("firstname")
        newUser.LastName = r.FormValue("lastname")
        var err error
        newUser.Balance, err = strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("balance"), 64)
        checkError(err)

        //open file
        file, err := os.OpenFile("list.json", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
        checkError(err)
        defer file.Close()

        //read file and unmarshall json file to slice of users
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        var alUsrs model.AllUsers
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &alUsrs.Users)
        checkError(err)
        max := 0

        //generation of id(last id at the json file+1)
        for _, usr := range alUsrs.Users {
            if usr.Id > max {
                max = usr.Id
            }
        }
        id := max + 1
        newUser.Id = id

        //appending newUser to slice of all Users and rewrite json file
        alUsrs.Users = append(alUsrs.Users, newUser)
        newUserBytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(&alUsrs.Users, "", " ")
        checkError(err)
        ioutil.WriteFile("list.json", newUserBytes, 0666)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)

    }

}

//index page handler
func IndexFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    au := model.ShowAllUsers()
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/indexPage.html")
    checkError(err)
    t.Execute(w, au)
}

//function to delete user
func DeleteUserFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/deleteUser.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        r.ParseForm()
        id, err := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("id"))
        checkError(err)

        //open file with users
        file, err := os.OpenFile("list.json", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
        defer file.Close()

        //read file and unmarshall json to []users
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        var alUsrs model.AllUsers
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &alUsrs.Users)
        checkError(err)

        var allID []int
        for _, usr := range alUsrs.Users {
            allID = append(allID, usr.Id)
        }
        for i, usr := range alUsrs.Users {
            if model.IsValueInSlice(allID, id) != true {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/deleteuser/notsuccededdelete", 302)
                return
            }
            if usr.Id != id {
                continue
            } else {
                alUsrs.Users = append(alUsrs.Users[:i], alUsrs.Users[i+1:]...)
            }

        }
        newUserBytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(&alUsrs.Users, "", " ")
        checkError(err)
        ioutil.WriteFile("list.json", newUserBytes, 0666)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/deleted", 301)
    }
}
//show user by it ID
func ShowUserFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/showUserPage.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)

    } else {

        id, err := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("id"))
        checkError(err)
        var alUsrs model.AllUsers
        file, err := os.OpenFile("list.json", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
        checkError(err)
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        checkError(err)
        json.Unmarshal(b, &alUsrs.Users)

        var allID []int
        for _, usr := range alUsrs.Users {
            allID = append(allID, usr.Id)
        }
        for _, usr := range alUsrs.Users {
            if model.IsValueInSlice(allID, id) != true {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/showuser/notsuccededshow/", 302)
                return
            }
            if usr.Id != id {
                continue
            } else {
                t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/showUserPage.html")
                checkError(err)
                t.Execute(w, usr)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

main.go

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"

    "test_Backend_ExpertSender/handlers"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/addnewuser/", handlers.AddNewUserFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/notsucceded", handlers.NotSucceded)

    http.HandleFunc("/deleted", handlers.DeletedFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/deleteuser/deleted", handlers.DeleteUserFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/deleteuser/", handlers.DeleteUserServe)
    http.HandleFunc("/deleteuser/notsuccededdelete", handlers.NotSuccededDelete)

    http.HandleFunc("/", handlers.IndexFunc)

    http.HandleFunc("/showuser/show", handlers.ShowUserFunc)
    http.HandleFunc("/showuser/", handlers.ShowUser)
    http.HandleFunc("/showuser/notsuccededshow/", handlers.NotSuccededShow)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)


}
```

model.go

```
    package model

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

//function which return is there a value in slice
func IsValueInSlice(slice []int, value int) (result bool) {
    for _, n := range slice {
        if n == value {
            return true
        }

    }
    return false

}

type User struct {
    Id        int     `json:"id"`
    FirstName string  `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string  `json:"lastName"`
    Balance   float64 `json:"balance"`
}

type AllUsers struct {
    Users []*User
}

func ShowAllUsers() (au *AllUsers) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile("list.json", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    checkError(err)
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    var alUsrs AllUsers
    json.Unmarshal(b, &alUsrs.Users)
    checkError(err)
    return &alUsrs
}
```

Comment: А где go код?  Что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: @biosckon я честно говоря не нашел даже,в какую сторону идти,formValue считывает ввод,думал использовать postFormValue,но это вроде разбирает сам запрос,можно ли это как-то реализовать с помощью методов request?

Comment: Покажите нам ваше приложение на Go. И далее мы уже сможем подумать. Вы спрашиваете о тестах Go кода а показываете HTML.

Comment: @biosckon сделано)правда,я думаю,будет ещё больше вопросов)

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие. Как откроют, напишем ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно тестировать handlers, примерно так:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", IndexFunc)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

**handlers.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func IndexFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    firstName := r.FormValue("firstname")
    lastName := r.FormValue("lastname")
    _, err := w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", firstName, lastName)))
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

**handlers_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/url"
    "testing"
)

func TestIndexFunc(t *testing.T) {
    rw := httptest.NewRecorder()

    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("firstname", "Иван")
    form.Add("lastname", "Петров")
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/", bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode()))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    // Вызов handler IndexFunc
    IndexFunc(rw, req)

    if rw.Result().StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Request code %v not equal code 200", rw.Code)
    }
    if rw.Body.String() != "Иван Петров" {
        t.Errorf(`Request body "%v" not equal body "Иван Петров"`, rw.Body.String())
    }
}
```